# Is it worth caching GetEnvironmentVariable in c#?

Tags: c#, environment-variables

I have a program that reads environment variables many times (not sure the exact count, but probably in the thousands).  I wanted to see if it would make sense to put them in a dictionary, as there are about 5 variables it uses over and over and over again.  My first thought was that GetEnvironmentVariable probably doesn't take too much overhead, as it would be always hitting memory.  I created the following test:

```
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();
        Dictionary<string, string> vals = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        vals["TargetRoot"] = "Hey";
        for (int i = 0; i < 5e6; i++)
        {
            var j = vals["TargetRoot"];
            if (j != null && j.Equals("hello there" + i))
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Dictionary: " + sw.Elapsed);
        sw.Restart();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5e6; i++)
        {
            var j = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TargetRoot");
            if (j != null && j.Equals("hello there" + i))
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("EnvVar: " + sw.Elapsed);
```

TargetRoot in this case is set, but will never satify the if condition.  The reason I added the if condition was so the compiler wouldn't short circuit.  The results are as follows:

Debug:

```
Dictionary: 00:00:00.8907373
EnvVar: 00:00:19.3848903
```

Retail:

```
Dictionary: 00:00:00.8625990
EnvVar: 00:00:19.3109294
```

Debug in the VS debugger:

```
Dictionary: 00:00:01.0370544
EnvVar: 00:00:04.9588787
```

Do you think this test is trustworthy, and can I conclude that GetEnvironmentVariable is 5-20 times slower than using a local cache?  Note that it seemed one of my cpus was at 100% during the 20 seconds, so I suspect it was more cpu bound than memory bound, but not positive.

Comment: We should really have a profiler for this kind of deal.

Comment: Something's not right. The second part should not be four times slower when run *outside* of a debugger.

Comment: [Have a look at the implementation of `GetEnvironmentVariable()`.](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/environment.cs,3956c71d4fc09576) It looks like it does some string manipulation and a call out to the Windows API.

Comment: It is not because environment variables are so slow, the "problem" is that a Dictionary is so enormously fast.  You can make any fast code take 5 seconds by repeating it often enough.  All and all, your program is slower by a handful of milliseconds, there isn't any way you can see that with the unaided eye.  But hey, if you want to write the code then don't let us discourage you.

Comment: Off of what @HansPassant discussed: Is the speed of `GetEnvironmentVariable()` actually causing a **meaningful** change in how your program is running? Is the speed gain by using a `Dictionary` worth the effort in you writing/implementing the code? If the answer to both of those is "yes" then by all means go for it, but it's likely not actually hurting anything as-is.